# UI-Router with Nested Views

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am having an issue getting UI-router working with  Nested Views.  I have a simple layout page with a Header, Nav, mainContainer.  I am just trying to get the Header and Nav injected as a Layout page and the mainContent will be driven from the Resource Pages.

However nothing shows up besides the initial layout.

I have created a Plunker to show the markup and code.

[Plunker Project](http://plnkr.co/edit/TRtzVA)

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="Portal">

  <head>
    <title>{{PageTitle}}</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.4.0-beta.5" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0-beta.5/angular.js"></script>
    <script data-require="ui-router@*" data-semver="0.2.13" src="//rawgit.com/angular-ui/ui-router/0.2.13/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; color: #000; font-weight: 900;">
    <div>
      <header>
        <div ui-view="header"></div>
      </header>
    </div>
    <div class="mainNav" style="top: 6vh;position: fixed; display: inline-block;border: 1px solid black;background: #620000;height: 97vh;border-top: 4px solid rgb(36,50,57); box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px 3px rgb(36,50,57);width: 10vw;max-width: 10vw;margin:0px; padding: 0px;">
      <div ui-view="profile"></div>
      <div ui-view="nav"></div>
    </div>
    <div style="width: 89vw;display: inline-block; border: 1px solid black;top: 6vh;left: 10vw;position: fixed;padding: .2%;height: 90vh;">
      <div ui-view="mainContainer"></div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Script.js

```
var app = angular.module('Portal', [ 'ui.router'  ]);   //, 'ngRoute', 'ngMessages',


app.config(function ($stateProvider) {


    $stateProvider
  .state('root',{
          url: '',
          abstract: true,          
          views: {
            'header': {
              templateUrl: 'Header.html'

            },
            'profile':{
              templateUrl: 'Profile.html'

            },
            'nav':{
                templateUrl: 'Nav.html'
            }
          }
        });

    $stateProvider    
    .state('root.index', {
          url: '/',
          views: {
            'mainContainer': {
              templateUrl: 'Sample.html'
            }
          }
        });

});
```

Header.html

```
<div>      
  This is the Text that should be in the heaeder
</div>
```

I use the same sample text for each nest view.

Comment: I am too lazy to fix the code :) please take a look at this for referance maybe this will help  https://scotch.io/tutorials/angular-routing-using-ui-router

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multiple issues:

1) check your templateUrl specification for profile view.

It is pointing to a  file that does not exist. templateUrl: 'Profile.html' You have named your file as 'Porfile.html'.

2) You are missing default route to "/". You corrected config should look like as follows:

```
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

    $stateProvider
     .state('root',{
          url: '',
          views: {
            'header': {
              templateUrl: 'Header.html'

            },
            'profile':{
              templateUrl: 'Porfile.html'

            },
            'nav':{
                templateUrl: 'Nav.html'
            }
          }
        });

    $stateProvider    
    .state('root.index', {
          url: '/',
          views: {
            'mainContainer': {
              templateUrl: 'Sample.html'
            }
          }
        });

});
```

3) Then in your index.html you are missing the script src tag for your javascript

```
    <script src="script.js"></script>
```

Comment: That worked! :-)  The default route you mentioned is the .otherwise()?